# PySpark: Sending each partition to same worker node for processing

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, rdd

I've a PySpark dataframe with 500+ clusters in the following format:

```
-------------------------------
| Cluster_num | text           |
-------------------------------
| 1           | some_text_1    |
-------------------------------
| 1           | some_text_2    |
-------------------------------
| 2           | some_text_3    |
-------------------------------
| 2           | some_text_4    |
-------------------------------
```

I want to apply `gensim.summarization` on the text of each cluster to get each cluster's summary. The dataset is huge and want to parallelize it to the maximum extent. Gensim is installed on all worker nodes.

Is there a way to apply this function in such a manner that all the text of same cluster goes to same worker nodes, where it could apply this summary function on it?

I was trying to convert it to `RDD` and then using `partitionBy` and `reduceByKey` but couldn't make it work.